# ERR_PNPM_OUTDATED_LOCKFILE Cannot install with "frozen-lockfile" because pnpm-lock.yaml is not up to date with package.json

Tags: node.js, vercel

ERR_PNPM_OUTDATED_LOCKFILE  Cannot install with "frozen-lockfile" because pnpm-lock.yaml is not up to date with package.json

ERR_PNPM_OUTDATED_LOCKFILE  Cannot install with "frozen-lockfile" because pnpm-lock.yaml is not up to date with package.json ven deploying to vercel

Comment: Please don't repeat text to get past our quality filters. If you're prompted to add more detail, _add more detail._